# Use IntentFiler in onPause()

Tags: android

I want to start my Application (ex update my TextView) after press back button. But it didn't work. Please help me.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        
   intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");  
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
}


protected void onPause() {
     registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
     super.onPause();

}

private  BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {           
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sendSMS("123","message"); 

    }
};
```

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do exactly.. means you want to start new activity on back press and also want to update text view.

Comment: Are you trying to set the textview for an Activity that is paused and possible stopped/destroyed?  When it calls back to onResume it is being re-inited anyway.  Maybe try storing the value in another variable that won't be erased.

Comment: I want to send a message to a phonenumber when my app is onPause() using function sendSMS. can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code try this and if any problem is there then ask me. I will try to help you ..

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // FOR UPDATING YOUR TEXT VIEW.
        Intent broadcast_intent = new Intent("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcast_intent.putExtra("number", textview_value_to_set);
        sendBroadcast(broadcast_intent);

        // // FOR STARTING YOUR NEW ACTIVITY.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), class_name.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Use this as your broadcast receiver. Dont forget to register reciever.

```
    private  BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {           
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION")) {
                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                text.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("number"));
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm want when my device receive a sms, it will send another sms to a phonenumber. My app worked when it on the foreground, but I need it still running on background. Can you help me? Sorry if you didn'd understand me. My English is so bad.

Comment: I think you should bind a service with your activity whenever your receive sms update UI of your activity using broadcast or any other way. In this way when you will be in background it will work without any problem.